# Add Field to Customer Registation Form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sql, customer-attribute, setup-script

I want to add a field/attribute to Customer Registration Form on frontend.
And I create a folder in my module , the folder is "Setup" and I put inside a file "InstallData.php" but this doesn't work.
this is the code:

```
<?php
namespace Riccardo\Plugin\Setup;


use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();


        $installer->addAttribute("customer", "promotion_code",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Promotion Code",
            "input"    => "text",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "promotion_code");


        $used_in_forms=array();

        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

After this I update the release of moduel and run this command from prompt:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Maybe this command is wrong ?
The source code is wrong?
What is wrong?

Please help me

Comment: You may use custom extension for this purpose https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Custom-Registration-Field.html

Answer (score 2):

first the code give you an error $installer->addAttribute undefined method

second  that

```
Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "promotion_code");
```

is not for mag2 is mag1 style.

the almost is :

```
<?php
namespace Ibnab\CustomerPut\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;





class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "promotion_code");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "promotion_code",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Promotion Code",
            "input"    => "text",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $promotion_code   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "promotion_code");

        $promotion_code = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'promotion_code');
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $promotion_code->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);

        $promotion_code->save();



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

screenshot from admin Account Information :
[image]

Comment: OK well. But how to import this config?
I mean what command I need to run for upgrade db,magento module, magento registration form and so on ?

Comment: OK works . Now I want to add this field to registration form . I mean that when a new customer open the "Create Account" page on frontend , Magento show this attribute , the "Promotion Code" attribute. How to do this?

Comment: The code works for the admin panel , but I want it works for all forms. For example the registrazion form from frontend doesn't work.
How can I extend this attribute to all forms??

Comment: you need some code create customer_account_create.xml  and use referenceContainer name="form.additional.info" to push .phtml and adding your custom code of fields 

 <input type="text" name="my_attribute" id="my_attribute" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Attribute') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off">

the first response in top is part of complete tutorials in :
http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer

Comment: It does not work for me. I cannot see the promotion code field in admin or the register form.

Answer (score 2):

> It does not work for me. I cannot see the promotion code field in admin or the register form. – zzpaul Jul 29 at 14:42

@zzpaul make sure you have created the customer_account_create.xml 
under your app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/frontend/layout folder

check that you have a custom .phtml file under app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/frontend/templates

this .phtml shold be referenced in the customer_account_create.xml where you should have something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your_new_block" before="-" as="customer-type" template="[Vendor_Module]::[custom_template].phtml"/>  
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

this is the layout where you say you are putting a new block (which uses the standard framework class Template instead of a custom you could have created) inside the existing container named form.additional.info which is located in the layout files of the core module-customer

in the phtml file you have to add the view elements you want to be rendered

Comment: Hi Andy this breaks the page for some reason, when i added the customer_account_create.xml file my account create status code is 500.

when i looked at the logs no issues i can't see any errors